# L'Hospital's Rule of infinity over infinity

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, infinity, indeterminate-forms

I am troubled for understanding the L'Hospital's Rule of $\infty/\infty$ :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)} \tag{1}$$

where $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\{f(x),g(x)\} \rightarrow \infty$.

The equation (1) is well understood for me in the case of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\{f(x),g(x)\} \rightarrow 0$, in which case :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a)+f^\prime(a)\Delta x}{g(a)+g^\prime(a)\Delta x}= \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)} \tag{2}$$

However, if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\{f(x),g(x)\} \rightarrow \infty$, here is my attempt :

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{1/g(x)}{1/f(x)}= \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{-\frac{1}{g^2(x)}g^\prime(x) }{-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}f^\prime(x)} \tag{3}$$

I don't understand why this last result can be turned into $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)}$?

Comment: You can turn $lim_{→\infty}\frac{()}{()} to lim_{→0}\frac{(1/)}{(1/)}$ and 1/x=y

Comment: Spivak's Calculus text has a careful series of exercises to do all the variations of L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Your proof in (2) makes sense but assumes $f$ and $g$ are differentiable in a neighborhood of $a$ (including point $a$ itself), that $f(a)=g(a)=0$, and that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f'(x)=f'(a)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g'(x) = g'(a)$. L'Hoptial's rule does hold more generally even when $f'(a)$ and $g'(a)$ do not exist.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Actually, Spivak gives the details only for $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x),g(x)=\infty$. One will have to modify it appropriately to do $\lim\limits_{x\to a}$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your great comment! If you can elaborate more or give me some references, I would be appreciate that!

Comment: Wikipedia for L'Hopital's rule works well: Note that it only requires $f$ to be differentiable on an open interval about $a$ but not necessarily at $a$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#:~:text=L'H%C3%B4pital's%20rule%20then%20states,provided%20that%20this%20is%20defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is the Intuition behind that.**
It lets you see the Conclusion in easy terms.

**View 1 :**

You have got this :
$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{1/g(x)}{1/f(x)}= \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{-\frac{1}{g^2(x)}g^\prime(x) }{-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}f^\prime(x)} \tag{3}$

Now , let $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L \tag{4}$

Then , we have $L= \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{-\frac{1}{g^2(x)}g^\prime(x) }{-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}f^\prime(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f^2(x)}{g^2(x)}\frac{g^\prime(x)}{f^\prime(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}L^2\frac{g^\prime(x)}{f^\prime(x)} \tag{5}$

Hence $\frac{1}{L}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{g^\prime(x)}{f^\prime(x)} \tag{6}$

Hence $L=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f^\prime(x)}{g^\prime(x)} \tag{7}$

**Alternate View 2 :**

We have $L= \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{-\frac{1}{g^2(x)}g^\prime(x) }{-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}f^\prime(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac{g^\prime(x)}{f^\prime(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}L\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac{g^\prime(x)}{f^\prime(x)} \tag{8}$

**The last term must be $1$ , hence that must involve $L$ times the reciprocal.**

$1=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\frac{g^\prime(x)}{f^\prime(x)} \tag{9}$

**OBSERVATION :**

No other value for the given term will be **Consistent** , over-all.
We can show that this value is Correct & valid though other ways , though this is the Intuitive way.

Comment: Indeed, the hard part is to show that the limit exists in the first place. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi, show the limit exists in Eq.(3) is hard, right?

Comment: Eq (4), you mean?

Comment: Correct , this Answer is more about the Intuition & the Consistency , @TedShifrin , the rigorous treatment will have to cover each & every "Corner-Case + Criteria" of LH rule. That is very hard !!

Comment: I do not think that this is helpful. A proof of  L'Hospital's Rule for the case $\infty/\infty$ requires a new approach. It is not reducible to the $0/0$ rule, the Ansatz $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{1/g(x)}{1/f(x)}$ does not produce a reasonable result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with $\frac{0}{0}$, then I would do the following:

1. $\frac{B}{A} = \frac{1}{\frac{A}{B}}$
2. In limits, you usually do $0 = \frac{1}{\infty}$
3. Let us say that our limit $L = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$.  You can also express $\frac{\infty}{\infty} = \frac{1}{\infty}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\infty}} = \frac{\frac{1}{\infty}}{\frac{1}{\infty}} = \frac{0}{0}$.
4. Because this is also a form of $\frac{0}{0}$ then L'Hospital's rule applies.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP has done.

Comment: This does *not* give the form of L'Hôpital's rule that we all expect, as the OP precisely observed.

Answer (score 1):

You idea does not help you to prove L'Hospital's Rule in the $\infty/\infty$-case. You only get the formula
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{1/g(x)}{1/f(x)}= \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{-\frac{1}{g^2(x)}g^\prime(x) }{-\frac{1}{f^2(x)}f^\prime(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f^2(x)}{g^2(x)} \cdot \frac{g^\prime(x) }{f^\prime(x)} $$
provided the limit on the RHS **exists**. But this does not follow from the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. We have to know **additionally** the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f^2(x)}{g^2(x)}$ which is up to sign the same as the existence of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.

Only in that case we can deduce that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ which is at best a computational help if we know that both limit exist. But the point of L'Hospital's Rule is that it suffices to know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists.

Indeed you need a separate proof in the $\infty/\infty$-case. It is not reducible to the $0/0$-case.